# How do I pass the category object to a function when is_archive() is true?

Tags: theme-development

The function below is typically used when inside a loop of categories in order to return each category's description. I'm trying to use it to return the individual category's description when viewing a category landing page (mysite/category/somecategory).

How do I pass the equivalent object that represents the category?

On header.php

```
if(is_archive()) {
//get the category description
echo get_cat_desc(get_query_var( 'category' ))
}
```

In functions.php

```
function get_cat_desc($category){
  $the_description = strip_tags($category->description);
  if(strlen($the_description) > 200 ) 
return  SUBSTR( $the_description,0,STRPOS( $the_description,".",200)+1);
else return  $the_description;
}
```

Here is the function where I'm successfully passing in the category object to the function above...

```
function my_category_index(){
$categories=get_categories('exclude=1&exclude_tree=1');
foreach($categories as $category) {echo ce4_get_cat_desc($category);}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get_cat_desc(get_category(get_query_var( 'category' )));
```

([get_category](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category))